# What is the coefﬁcient of $x^7$ in $(1 + x)^{11}$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

What is the coefficient of $x^7$ in $(1 + x)^{11}$?

I don't know how to solve this question please help me

Comment: Hint: Binomial Coefficient.

Comment: I've edited your post to include MathJax; please verify that it says what you intended. Are you familiar with the binomial theorem?

Comment: No I'm not familiar with that can you help me?

Comment: Amzoti and T.Bongers *did* help you. Look up the binomial theorem. It's relatively important that you know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the expression: $$(1+x)(1+x)...(1+x) $$ 11 times. You will have a term $x^7$ exactly when you choose $7 x's$  and $4$ $1$'s  from the $11$ parentheses.
 How many ways can you choose $7$ $x$'s out of the $11$ parentheses?